# Copy in-memory SQLite Database to make unit tests faster

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, nhibernate

In C#/nHibernate-projects I am using SQLite to unit test my code, aproximately using the method described here: http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing.

However, I find that building and configuring the in-memory database typically takes about 150ms. I have lots of unit test so this rapidly adds up.

I want to build and configure the database once, store it in a static variable, and copy it every time a unit test needs a database.

**How do I back-up an in-memory database?**

I first tried to create a named in-memory database. According to https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html this is possible. I used to have:

```
    private const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;";
```

Connection strings I tried are:

```
    private const string ConnectionString = "FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";
    private const string ConnectionString2 = "FullUri=file:memorydb2.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";
```

So now I just have to find out how to quickly copy content from one to another?
I'm almost there: I can create two in-memory databases, and call "BackupDatabase" to copy the database.

The unit test however, behaves like the "instance" database has no tables, even the "prototype" database does.

```cs
        private static ISessionFactory _prototypeSessionFactory;
        private const string InstanceConnectionString = "FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";

        private const string PrototypeConnectionString = "FullUri=file:memorydb2.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";
        private SQLiteConnection _instanceConnection;
        private ISessionFactory _instanceSessionFactory;

        public DatabaseScope(Assembly assembly)
        {
            var prototyeConfiguration = SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(PrototypeConnectionString);
            var cfg = Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(prototyeConfiguration)
                .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly));
            cfg.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);
            _prototypeSessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            var instanceConfiguration = SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(InstanceConnectionString);
            _instanceSessionFactory = Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(instanceConfiguration)
                .BuildSessionFactory();

            CopyDatabase();
        }

        private void CopyDatabase()
        {
            var cnnIn = new SQLiteConnection(PrototypeConnectionString);
            var cnnOut = new SQLiteConnection(InstanceConnectionString);
            cnnIn.Open();
            cnnOut.Open();
            cnnIn.BackupDatabase(cnnOut, "main", "main", -1, null, -1);
            cnnIn.Close();
            cnnOut.Close();
        }
```

Comment: according to [this article](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html)(look at loadOrSaveDb example). It seems that you need to use `sqlite3_backup_init()` with a pointer to the destination DB. However I don't think it will solve your problem. your tests sound like an integration tests not UT. I think you should consider to use a mocking framework and replace your DB.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Old Fox. You are right: they are partly integration test. And they work perfectly, just a bit slow, which hurts for 300+ tests.
I'm not looking forward to rewriting that many tests, but for the sake of argument: how would you go about replacing the database using a mocking framework?
(I consider what I'm doing mocking: I'm using SQLite to mock my database, making sure that everything works als long as my nHibernate mappings are correct.)

Comment: I think 300+ integration tests which verify the mapping is a bit too much... I believe your code work directly against `NHibernate`. If so, I'd advice you to split the tests into 2 kinds:
1. behaviour + call the OEM correctly(fake OEM. probably most of your exists tests). 
2. Integration Tests - OEM mapped the type correctly(probably 10% from the 300+ tests).

About faking the DB, forget about it, it was my fault....

Comment: Your 10% is about right. My code base has about 2500 unit tests, 300 involving faked databases. Most of the actual work is done in the database, things like the correct tariff being selected for the correct type of customer and date range. The actual query for these kinds of things is written in c#, linq to nHibernate. Again- the actual tests correctly verify if functionality works as expected. Just a bit too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this working code.
My unit test duration went from over ten minutes to under two minutes.
(Code slightly simplified for readability)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Mapping;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;

namespace TestHelper.DbHelper.SqLite
{
    public class DatabaseScope : IDisposable
    {
        private static Assembly _prototypeAssembly;
        private const string PrototypeConnectionString = "FullUri=file:prototype.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";
        private static ISessionFactory _prototypeSessionFactory;
        private static SQLiteConnection _prototypeConnection;

        private const string InstanceConnectionString = "FullUri=file:instance.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";
        private ISessionFactory _instanceSessionFactory;
        private SQLiteConnection _instanceConnection;

        public DatabaseScope(Assembly assembly)
        {
            InitDatabasePrototype(assembly);
            InitDatabaseInstance();
        }

        private void InitDatabasePrototype(Assembly assembly)
        {
            if (_prototypeAssembly == assembly) return;

            if (_prototypeConnection != null)
            {
                _prototypeConnection.Close();
                _prototypeConnection.Dispose();
                _prototypeSessionFactory.Dispose();
            }

            _prototypeAssembly = assembly;

            _prototypeConnection = new SQLiteConnection(PrototypeConnectionString);
            _prototypeConnection.Open();

            _prototypeSessionFactory = Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(PrototypeConnectionString))
                .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, _prototypeConnection, null))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        private void InitDatabaseInstance()
        {
            _instanceSessionFactory = Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(InstanceConnectionString))
                .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(_prototypeAssembly))
                .BuildSessionFactory();

            _instanceConnection = new SQLiteConnection(InstanceConnectionString);
            _instanceConnection.Open();

            _prototypeConnection.BackupDatabase(_instanceConnection, "main", "main", -1, null, -1);
        }

        public ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return _instanceSessionFactory.OpenSession(_instanceConnection);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _instanceConnection.Close();
            _instanceConnection.Dispose();
            _instanceSessionFactory.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have observed with SQLite in memory databases is that as soon as you close the connection, everything in the db is gone. So to do what you want,

1. Create session factory for the backup database, open session and build schema don't close this session until you finish your entire test suite
2. Create session factory for your target database, open session and use the connection from this session object and the connection from session created from step 1 to copy data
3. Use the session created on step 2 for test and close it once test is finished

Another solution is to use the single session to perform multiple tests (all the tests in single test fixture) then you do not need to create new session factory per test, but per testfixture

Comment: Isn't building the schema the most time consuming part of creating an sqlite database from nhibernate-mappings? That's the step I am trying to circomvent...
There is no "truncate all tables"-command, is there?

Comment: I'm not sure schema creation is the bottleneck or, creating and establish connectivity. One option for this is to create in memory db once and reuses the same session for multiple tests with transaction creation at each test start and rolling back at end of the test.

Comment: Jip. I got it working folliwing your instructions. I referenced the wrong db somewhere else in the code.