# Unit test crashes because it doesn't know my database table

Tags: c#, unit-testing

My application works fine, but when I'm `unit testing` it crashes. The error output is the following:

> "Message: Test method MyUnitTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod threw an
>   exception:  SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: Game".

This is the code of the unit test:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WishListProject.ViewModels;

namespace MyUnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            //Arrange
            var vm = new GameListViewModel();


            vm.GameNaamEntry = "WoW:Classic";
            vm.GameGenreEntry = "MMORPG";
            vm.GameReleaseEntry = "27/08/2019";
            //Act
            vm.AddGameCommand.Execute(null);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(vm.Games, "Games variabele is leeg"); 

        }
    }
}
```

This is the line where it crashes (doesn't recognise "Game" as a Table):

```
Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>(db.Table<Game>().OrderBy(x => x.GameNaam).ToList());
```

I find it really weird because when I just test my application it works as it should and doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Unit tests probably shouldn't know about the database, that's more an integration test - are you bootstrapping your database in your unit tests? If not, could that be the issue - that your application creates the db context but your unit tests do not? What's the definition of `db` in your `GameListViewModel`?

Comment: If you use something like Moq you can build a fixed simulation of what should be returned when your unit test requests data from your theoretical database. This would enable you to test the code/logic rather than what kind of data is in the database.

Comment: @Charleh string _dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myWishList.db3"); // var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

Comment: @Charleh What do you mean with bootstrapping? I'm new to this

Comment: When/where does this code which creates the connection happen? Can you update the question with your full view model code?

Answer (score 2):

Unit Tests are for testing small chunks of code. In your case, you may want to create a mock version of your Games object.

I'm assuming that your call fails as your Unit Test does not have a valid database connection when it's running the tests.

Ideally, you don't want to be making database calls each time you run a unit test anyway. They should be quick to run so you can run them often. You could set up more complex tests in another project, but this would not be a unit test, more of an integration test. How you implement this is up to you and the tech stack you are working with.

Comment: People don't understand the difference in Unit tests and Integration tests. Everything is Unit test if you are using a Testing Framework.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that You don't understand the [difference in Unit tests and Integration tests](https://www.softwaretestingclass.com/what-is-difference-between-unit-testing-and-integration-testing/)

In my opinion, you had better do the following some ways

1. [Copy in-memory SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073478/copy-in-memory-sqlite-database-to-make-unit-tests-faster)
2. [Testing with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)

**FYI:**

> SQLite has an in-memory mode that allows you to use SQLite to write tests against a relational database, without the overhead of actual database operations

Note that:

> Make sure unit tests are `separated from integration tests`